# MySql: Check where clause for all row returned by an inner join

Tags: mysql, inner-join, where-clause

I have this query

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
INNER JOIN categories ON categories.post_id = posts.id
INNER JOIN tags ON tags.category_id = categories.id
WHERE tags.title = 'week_trend'
```

Each posts has multiple categories and also each category has multiple tags and I need the posts that have the categories with the specified tag but all the post categories should have this condition and even if one of those categories failed the condition the post shouldn't be included. My query returns the posts even if one of their categories has the specified tag.

I almost have no idea how to do it can someone help me tnx

Comment: When joining posts and categories, shouldn't you specify a column from posts and a column from categories? You are specifying 2 columns from categories.

Comment: Yea that's right thanks, but its just a smaple code for presenting my problem it's not a big deal

Comment: It's not a big deal? I don't see how anybody can offer help if you post incorrect code.

Comment: Your description of what you want is unintelligible. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. To describe a result: Say enough that someone could go away & come back with a solution. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. See [ask], other [help] links, hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization. [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097)

Comment: @philipxy I just needed help and I described the condition by a sample code. It's short and it gives enough information. forpas gave an answer that wasn't completely correct but helped me a lot and showed me the way. He exactly got what I need so there is nothing wrong with my question I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT c.post_id
FROM categories c INNER JOIN tags t
ON t.category_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.post_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) = SUM(t.title = 'week_trend')
```

returns all the `post_id`s with categories that are all related to the tag with title `'week_trend'`.
Use it with an `IN` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts 
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT c.post_id
  FROM categories c INNER JOIN tags t
  ON t.category_id = c.id
  GROUP BY c.post_id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) = SUM(t.title = 'week_trend')
)
```

Comment: This  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) = SUM(t.title = 'week_trend')  helped me a lot thanks.